# In Azure Portal I didn't find this option while adding Add role assignment -> Assign Access to -> "Azure AD user, group, or service principle"

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

I just created my account with Free subscription, And want to assign role in "My Permission" for Contributor as "Azure AD user, group, or service principle"
[image: Azure Role Assignment 1]

But i only find this option "User, group, or service principle".

Please guide me properly if I am missing something or how can I enable or get that option.

Thanks,

Adeel

Answer (score 0):

I think you are referencing Azure documentation "Add Azure role assignments"

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/role-based-access-control/role-assignments-portal#add-a-role-assignment

I opened an issue in MicrosoftDocs GitHub to clarify misspelling in documentation.
https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/issues/68645

**Update 2021-01-14:**
*Answer from Microsoft*

*The details refer to the same thing but we will get the screenshot updated.*

**Documentation is updated**

Comment: Okay, So do you know why it shows only "User, group, service principle" only why Azure AD User not there?

Comment: I also added new Subscription for "Pay you go" but still its not visible :(

Comment: I think there were recent changes in Azure role assignments functionality, but documentation was not updated yet. GitHub issue should make clarification https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/issues/68645

Comment: Answer from Microsoft:
The details refer to the same thing but we will get the screenshot updated.